# Google API Explorer 403 Access Not Configured

Tags: android, api, http, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to use the Google API Explorer to test my Google Play Game Services backend.
No matter what I do, the requests in the Google API Explorer always return "*Access Not Configured. The API (Google Play Game Services API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration*"

[Google API Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1wgP.png)

I do believe that I have enabled the correct API's in the developer console

[Google Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkS4k.png)

The requests are working in my deployed Android application.

My questions boil down to:

- Do I need to perform any additional setup in the Developer Console to use the Google API Explorer?
- Can the Google API Explorer be used in the way that I want it to, ie. to call HTTP requests to my Google Play Games Services?
- How are the requests sent from Google API Explorer linked to my
  specific app? For example, the games.leaderboards.list doesnt take any arguments from me - how can it know which app to get leaderboards from?

Comment: What api and what method? If you can share your http request, that'd help. Don't forget to authorize your requests with OAuth2, if you haven't already (top right-ish there's a switch/button). I believe some of the requests for Play Games Services API require things like the [application to be linked too](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application). This means you may have to do some things in the **Play Developer Console** as well.

Comment: One example of a request could be [this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/games/v1/games.achievementDefinitions.list?_h=2&) which should get all achievement definitions of our game.
How this is linked to our specific application in any way, I am not sure about.
The "Linked App" in the backend has been set up correctly, the apps are linked and I have the application ID and so on. I just don't see how I can use this information together with the Google API Explorer.

Comment: Looks like same thing happens to me too. Maybe it's an issue with the API explorer?